# Select * with one Group By Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to `select *` from a table and group by only one column. I am new to SQL, so a basic questions. My query looks like this.

```
Select top 10
    [DocumentClass], [DocumentUID]
    ,[DocumentClassification]
    ,[DocumentNumber]
    ,[Revision]
    ,[Description]
    ,[Owner]
from 
    Table
Group BY 
    [DocumentClass]
```

Error I am getting:

> Column 'DocumentUID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: When you use Group by all the columns in the select query must be added to Group by clause. You can only use summary of the columns(MAX,SUM,COUNT etc) in the select Statement. Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Comment: Thanks.. so that means i have to put all the columns in Group By which are in Select Clause of this query...but will it do the job of Grouping the results By a specific column?

Comment: No Definitely not. But it depends on what summary do you want out of Group By. Since you are grouping the records, if the rows have different values in different columns obviously they will be treated as seperate Group. You will have to use inner queries or CTE for retrieving the final result, after grouping in the inner query

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get one row per document class, then use `row_number()` instead of `group by`:

```
Select top 10 t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by documentclass order by newid()) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

`row_number()` is a function that enumerates the rows.  In this case, each document class will start over.  `newid()` is just a way of choosing a random row.

Normally, when you use `group by`, you would also have aggregation functions such as `min()` or `sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

This error means the SQL Server doesn't know which column do you want to use.
When you use GROUP BY command you want to select one specific value ( MIN, SUM, or AVG) or u want all ( count that rows ) .
You get all necessary information from this site. [GROUP BY](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php)